# Find any word in a sentence

Tags: java

First post and all that. I'm a novice programmer.

Anyway, I was tasked with created a program in Java that will take in user input in the form of a sentence AND a word. The program removes spaces from the sentence, and checks if the word is present in the "blank-less" sentence. However, the program also removes a letter from the end of the word, and checks if *that* word is present in the blank-less sentence. The program continues to remove letters from the word until there are no more letters to remove.

In addition, the program is also supposed to state the location of the word but it cannot list one location multiple times. If the program cannot find the whole word, it prints out "'Word' was not found." If it is, it prints out "'Word' was found at location 'x'"

*e.g. If my sentence is "She sings by the river" and by word is "byte", the code is supposed to check "shesingsbytheriver" for "byte", "byt", "by", and "b", but it CANNOT find "byt", "by", and "b" in the same location.*

Below is the code I have. Everything is fine up until my if statement. Instead of finding the word in the blank-less sentence, it continues to print out "'Word' was not found."

A few last notes: I should avoid arrays, and most of the commands I need are in String class.

Thanks!

```
// The purpose of this program is to take in user input in the form
// of a sentence and a word. The program repeats the sentence and word
// back, removes the spaces, and checks if the word was present in the
// sentence. The program removes a letter from the word, checks if that
// "word" is present and continues until it cannot remove any more letters.

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentenceBlankless;

        String sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a sentence: ");
        String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a word: ");

        sentenceBlankless = sentence.replaceAll(" ", "");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The original imput is: " + sentence);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Removing blanks - " + sentenceBlankless);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input word - " + word);

        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {

            if (sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                int loc = sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word.substring(0, word.length() - x) + " was found at location " + loc);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word.substring(0, word.length() - x) + " was not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but you should consider creating a list of the searches that are found and presenting this to the user instead of spamming the user with dialog boxes for each search found. Finally, welcome to stackoverflow and congrats on making your first post!

Comment: @Smac89 Ah right, that. My teacher requested specifically that we "spam" the user, forgot to mention that haha.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

The statement `if (sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))` doesn't take into account that you are looking for a shorter version of `word` each time.  Instead of just showing a shortened version to the user in your dialog box, you could instead chop the `word` shorter on each iteration:

```
word = word.substring(0, word.length() - x)
```

But that will break your `for` loop.

Which leads me to comment #2.  You could just as easily to this as a `while` loop:

```
while(word.length() > 0)
```

As for not being able to find the same word at the same location multiple times, that's a little bit trickier.  Probably the easiest way to do it would be with an array of `boolean`s, with each array element representing an index in the string:

```
boolean[] foundPositions = new boolean[sentenceBlankless.length];
```

Handily the [boolean primitive defaults to false](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).  So each time you find the instance of the `word` substring at a position, you set the flag in your array.

Then you need to check the array each time you search for the `word`, and if it has already been found, try the search again *but start from **position** this time*.  If you have covered recursion already, this is a good time to practice it.  This is some pseudo code (since I'm not going to do your homework completely) that shows how I would approach this:

```
private int FindPosition(string sentence, string word)
{
    find the index of word in sentence

    if not found
        return -1

    // We know sentence contains word
    if not previously found
        return found index

    // We know it was found, but has been found before, let's try again
    // but cut out the where it was found last time
    // This is recursion (calling a method from within the method)
    return FindPosition(sentence.substring, word)
}
```

Be aware of updating the flag array, and the specific substring you need to pass back in the recursive method.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?  The recursive method idea is only to handle whether the word input has been found at this position already. The loop to shorten the wordInput shouldn't be inside this method, it should call it. Go back and review variable scope, and see if you can work out why you can't declare the boolean array inside the method. Best advice, insert some print statements liberally throughout your code to run it and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it's always searching if "byte" was found, and not substrings of byte.

This happens on this line

```
if (sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
```

You always use `word` which is always "byte", it's never updated.

So you can replace it with

```
if (sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().contains(word.substring(0, word.length() - x).toLowerCase()))
```

but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead try updating word on every iteration of the for loop.

So you can do:

```
word = word.substring(0, word.length() - x);
```

Your final for loop would be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++)
{
    word = word.substring(0, word.length() - x);
    if (sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))
    {
        int loc = sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " was found at location " + loc);
    }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word + " was not found");

}
```

Everything else can stay unchanged.

Offtopic:

Inside the if statement `loc` uses `sentence` instead of `sentenceBlankless` to get the location.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get out of bounds errors. Which is weird because i didn't play with the string lengths

Comment: Edit: Error on my part, tried printing out the word with (word.substring(0, word.length() - x) in addition to having that in the loop.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have mentioned that I changed that part as well. Also regarding not printing the same location twice, you could use a hashmap, however, I wasn't not sure how your instructor wants you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider `break`ing out of the loop if the word was not found

```
if (sentenceBlankless.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
    int loc = sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word.substring(0, word.length() - x) + " was found at location " + loc);
}
else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, word.substring(0, word.length() - x) + " was not found");
    break; // break out of the loop
}
```

Comment: Ah, the thing is, my teacher doesn't like break statements either. He claims it leads to bad code. Personally I disagree.